# static in class declaration vs static in function

Tags: php, class, static

```
class A{

  static $var = true;

  function f(){

  }

}
```

vs

```
class A{

  function f(){
    static $var = true;

  }
}
```

There doesn't seem to be any difference. Are there any advantages of using one over the other?

Note that `$var` would be used in  the `f()` function only. I understand that declaring it in the class header is required if the variable needs to be used in multiple functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the later example you may only use the var inside the `f` function. The other is accessible anywhere from inside the class `A::var` or outside `A::var`

Answer (score 3):

If you only use the static variable in the `f` function, there's only a scope difference, that means no difference as long as you don't try to use it elsewhere.

When used in local scope, the static variable value is kept between each function call. See Static variables part of [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Thanks insertusernamehere for pointing that out.

Comment: I also would presume that `static $var` in a function is a logic error even if it's allowed by the PHP engine

Comment: That's not entirely true. A static variable in a function *caches* its value for the next call: "*Another important feature of variable scoping is the static variable. A static variable exists only in a local function scope, but it does not lose its value when program execution leaves this scope.*", from the PHP manual: "[Using static variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)".